# shall we write a wrapper on ag-grid library in angular 2

Tags: ag-grid

In Angular documentation, they suggested that Ag-grid/primeNg grid is the best grid.But the question is shall we write a wrapper on Ag-grid? If it is available, is there any documentation for developing a wrapper on Ag-grid in Angular 2.

Answer (score 1):

ag-grid offers already a wrapper for angular...

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-getting-started

Comment: HI Alberto. I agreed with your comment. But ag-grid-angular is on angular 2. for instance if i want migrate from later versions, again i need to re-write the code.

Answer (score 0):

Who recommended, who is they??? +1 on Alberto, already a wrapper provided by ag-grid team.

Comment: We are planning to write our own angular 2 wrapper on core ag-grid with limited functionality. If so how do we proceed?